# The composition of soft curves is not always soft.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

An exercise I found in one of my text books:

(In my book a curve that is "soft by pieces" is a curve $\gamma :[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there is a partition $P=\{a=t_0<t_1<...t_k=b\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that $\gamma$ has a continuous derivative on each $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ for $i \in \{1,2,...k\}$; I believe "soft by pieces" may not be a universal term to refer to such curves, this is a direct translation of the term used in the book, which is in Spanish)

''If $\gamma :[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\textit{soft by pieces}$ and $\alpha:[c,d]\subset\mathbb{R}\to[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, surjective on $[a,b]$ and $C^1$ on $[c,d]$. Show, with an example, that $\gamma \circ \alpha:[c,d]\subset\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is not always soft by pieces"

I took $\gamma:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $\gamma(t)=(t,|t|)$, I know that this function is soft by pieces (I need only to take $P=\{-1,0,1\}$, $\gamma$'s derivative is definitely continuous in $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$).
The problem I'm faced with lies in finding the adequate $\alpha$, at first I thought about proposing a function similar to $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ such that this function is surjective, but has problems on 0, the problem with this function is that is is not differentiable on zero. Then I thought about $x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, however these don't work either because even though I could make them continuous on zero (by defining a function that is 0 if $x=0$ and $x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ or $x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$) everywhere else) and their derivative is continuous, they are not surjectve on $[-1,1]$

I believe that my intuition about my choice if $\gamma$ is sound and the idea of choosing an $\alpha$ that "has problems on zero" could work. Still, I'm stuck and unable to find an $\alpha$ that "has problems on zero", but is surjective and has a continuous derivative.

Comment: In English we say the function is *piecewise smooth* (or piecewise continuously differentiable).

Comment: @TedShifrin thaks! c:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fine idea. Let$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}$$Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Let $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$ be the smallest number greater than $0$ such that $f(\alpha)=1$ ($\alpha\approx1.14$). And now consider the minimum of $f(x)$ when $x\in(0,\alpha]$; let us call $\beta$ the point at which that minimum is reached ($\beta\approx0.234$) and let $\eta=f(\beta)$ ($\eta\approx-0.05$). For each $x\in[\eta,1]$, let $\gamma(x)=|x|$. Then $f$ maps $[0,\alpha]$ onto $[\eta,1]$, $f|_{[0,\alpha]}$ is a $C^1$ function, $\gamma$ is piecewise differentiable, but $\gamma\circ f|_{[0,\alpha]}$ isn't: there are infinitely many points at which it is *not* differentiable.